# How can I create a QgsRubberBand with holes?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I tried to create a QgsRubberBand object with holes, but failed:

```
rb = QgsRubberBand(iface.mapCanvas(),True)
geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt("POLYGON((0 0,4 0,4 3,0 3,0 0),(1 1,3 1,3 2,1 2,1 1))")
rb.setToGeometry(geom,None)
```

Looks like QgsRubberBand doesn't recognize holes at all.
Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: in QgsRubberBand constructor the II parameters is the geometry type of the rubber band... polygon has value 2 as specified in: http://qgis.org/api/group__core.html#ga09947eb19394302eeeed44d3e81dd74b

Comment: Even with the correct geometry type the rubber band doesn't appear to respect geometries with holes.

Answer (score 1):

The `QgsRubberBand` does not support holes. The rubberband it is the kind of thing that is used to represent an ongoing action with the mouse. You would use it to draw the shell of a polygon or cut a hole from an existing shell.

If you need support for holes, you need to use [QgsHighlight](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsHighlight.html) instead.

Comment: I just looked up the `QgsHighlight` but as far as I can tell it needs a (source?) layer to work. The highlight part I need is just to be able to send it a geometry which like in the original question doesn't come from a layer.